# Cost attribute not displaying for some products

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I have a strange situation where the cost attribute is being displayed in the product edit form for some products but not others. There doesn't seem to be any correlation between the products that it works for and the products that it doesn't.

By looking in the database I can see that the cost is being saved but when you load the edit product -> price form it is blank in the input field.

Anyone have any ideas about where to look to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

“Cost” option is applied to all types of products? You can make it in such way: At back-end go to Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes and find “cost “ attribute. At “Properties” label for this attribute check that at “Apply to” field option “All product types” is chosen.

Comment: Yes thanks - I have already tried that. The products are all of the same type anyway.